# Why cant I use return statement in try block

Tags: java

Here it is giving error as method must return Integer even though registerUser in userCreationDao returns Integer itself.

```
public Integer registerUser(User user) {
    try{
        return userCreationDao.registerUser(user);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. In your `catch` you don't return an Integer. You'll have to return one. If an exception occurs the `catch` triggers, the original `return` gets skipped.

Comment: Wait...is this method within the class that `userCreationDao` is an instance of?

Answer (score 3):

Reason being, if you write something in the `try` block it is specific/confined only to try block i.e. if you initialize a variable inside the `try` block, you cannot use it outside its scope. Below code causes a compile time error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        int a=10;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

In a similar way, if you return something in `try` block, its scope is restricted to `try` block but instead it has to be at the method level.

Imagine a case, where you write something before your return statement in the `try` block as below:

```
 public Integer registerUser(User user) {
        try{
         // some code
            return userCreationDao.registerUser(user);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If the `//some code` causes an error, it would be handled in Exception. Then?? where does the code go? It is already past the return statement, it has nowhere to go. This is the reason why your code is stating otherwise.

**Alternate** flow to this is, you need to have an other `return` statement in `catch` block and hence the return would be at the method level as the code would be returned either from `try/catch`

> Why cant I use return statement in try block

you can use a return statement inside the `try` block, but you have to place another return outside the `try` block as well.

```
public class tryBloc {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(sayHello(false));
    }

    public static boolean sayHello(boolean i){
        try{
            if(i)
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

If you pass `true` while calling sayHello method, it would return from `try` block.

A `return` statement has to be at the method level instead of at any other specific level.

Comment: Method just have to always return something or throw, This does not mean return has to be at the method level. Return can be in both try block and catch block, with no return outside try-catch block

Comment: Hi @Piro, Even if we have return in both try and catch, it is an error. In my example, if you re-write return false in the catch block, it would throw an error. give it a try

Comment: Yes because you return only when condition is reached. But that does not mean you need return outside try-catch in general. You can have another return right after `if(i) return true;` and return in catch block

Comment: @Piro    ,  Correct,if it is in both try and catch, then it is at the method scope, because it will either return from try/catch.

Comment: @Piro, alternate flow i.e. addition of return statement in the catch block has been mentioned in the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the method to return value, even if an exception occurs.

```
 public Integer registerUser(User user) {
int value =-1;
try{
    value=userCreationDao.registerUser(user);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return value;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of these two things, because if an exception is thrown, your method never returns a value.

```
public Integer registerUser(User user) {
    try{
        return userCreationDao.registerUser(user);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

or

```
public Integer registerUser(User user) {
    try{
        return userCreationDao.registerUser(user);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: *You need to do one of these two things...* No, there are plenty of alternatives, including `throw null;`, `return 1;` and `while (true);`.